# aiomultiprocess. Глобальная область видимости

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Использую **aiomultiprocess** в связке с Windows.

Подобный код в Linux проходит без проблем, но в Windows бросает ошибку "x не определён, ну нет такой и всё, чё пристал"

```
from aiomultiprocess import Process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = ['list']
    print('x was born')

async def coro():
    print(x) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=coro).start()
```

Так вот, можно ли как-то создать глобальную область видимости в aiomultiprocess чтобы новые процессы не пересоздавали переменные, а брали их из области `__main__`?

Видел подобное в multiprocessing as mlp(mlp.Array,mlp.Value), но в aio версии такого нет. Прошу помочь, спасибо!

Comment: @NotStatiko я конечно не эксперт, но можно использовать очередь, чтобы использовать его в разных процессах

Comment: @danilshik, так, а где можно почитать? Можешь вбросить ссылку?